# What do you suppose is causing the separation and disintegration of these bricks?

Tags: foundation, brick, cracks

This is no longer my problem, but I'm curious what you assume is happening here. On the inside, the floor appears to be sinking towards the center of the house. Another area of brick is leaning away from the window.
[image]

Comment: At a guess, water, either acting as such or freezing and expanding in the mortar joints.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me without knowing if you have cold winters or not, that water has collected in the wall and froze which pushed out the mortar. With the picture provided I can't tell if the concrete slab goes into the wall or stops at it like it should. My thought is it goes into the wall blocking the water from draining, typically through weep holes at the foundation level.